# Error de laravel 1071 Specified key was too long

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el problema de laravel de

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` a
dd unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
```

Y he hecho lo que sale en laravel como solucion de ir a App/providers y añadir un codigo y aun sigue el problema, incluso en las migraciones le coloque una longitud a los emails y aun me sigue tirando el problema, a que se debera?

Aqui codigo de AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Aqui el codigo de las 2 migraciones que trae laravel por defecto, donde les coloque la longitud.

migration de create_user_Table.php

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email', 250)->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Y la de create_password_reset.php

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('email', 250)->index();
        $table->string('token');
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontré la solución, solo con añadir en `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
    {

    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

    }
```

Es suficiente, si se colocó una longitud anteriormente en los emails de las migraciones, hay que quitarlo sino seguirá lanzando el error 1071.

Comment: marca tu respuesta como aceptada para dar por resuelta esta pregunta

Comment: Si no me equivoco, cuando añades esto no permites poder guardar "Emojis" y esto podria ser un problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tenia el mismo problema y lo resolví en el archivo `config/database.php`

```
'mysql' => [
        ...
        ...
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', //Tu base de datos debe tener este cotejamiento
        ...
        ...
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    ]
```

Luego abres desde la consola ejecutas el comando

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

y ya puedes realizar tus migraciones con normalidad, si no quieres borrar toda la cache, puedes borrar solo la cache de `config`

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score -1):

Solo con añadir en **AppServiceProvider.php**:

```
public function boot() {
    Schema::defaultStringLength('191');
}
```

Comment: Se te agradece la intención de ayuda pero si revisas tu solución es la misma que el OP de hecho ya publico